# Fill multiple list with for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have several list want to be filled with values in python.

I am thinking to use a loop to fill the lists:

Here are some initial code I was trying:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = ([] for i in range(4)) 
for i in range(4):
    target_list_name = 'list'+ str(i)
    target_list_name = i
```

I do not think this is giving me what I want, the desire output is:

```
print(list1) [0]
print(list2) [1]
print(list3) [2]
print(list4) [3]
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you think a `list` is - you have it right when you're declaring them initially, but then your desired output seems to have `list1`, `list2`, ... as integers, rather than as lists.

Comment: `'list1'` is not `list1`.

Comment: How should I correct the code so I can assign each list different value as i increases?

Comment: @KeruChen Checkout my answer. List has a collection of value.

Comment: are you looking for `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]` ? or  `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: I think I am looking for something that I can keep the lists as individuals, maybe not like [[1], [2], [3], [4]], but more like, when I call list1, it contains some values, and so on so force.

Comment: so what exactly do you want? if you want `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]` then `print(list1)` gives you `[0]` and not `0`

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/wiki/faq#wiki_how_do_i_make_variable_variables.3F

Comment: Yes, you are correct, list1 will contain element of 0, so will be print(list1) as [0]. @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Then please fix the code to reflect that, and you don't need 4 variables for doing this

Comment: Thanks @KeruChen see if my answer below makes sense to you

Answer (score 1):

You have been really close with first line of your code.

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = ([i] for i in range(4))
```

Comment: but print(list1) will give `[0]` and the OP wants `0`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, I think he done a mistake, cause his desired output doesn't match name "list"

Comment: I have asked the same to OP

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dictionary`

```
>>> list_dict = {}
>>> for i in range(4):
...     list_dict[f'list{i+1}'] = [i]
... 
>>> list_dict
{'list1': [0], 'list2': [1], 'list3': [2], 'list4': [3]}
>>> print(list_dict['list1'])
[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach `target_list_name = 'list'+ str(i)` actually makes 4 strings which are `"list1"`, `"list2"` etc. They do not refer to the 4 list variables you defined before, as you might have thought.

In any case, you don't need 4 variables to hold sublists like that, you can create a list of lists and then refer to the sublists via indexes on the outer list

```
#Make a list with 4 sublists
li = [[i] for i in range(4)]

#Print each sublist
for item in li:
    print(item)
```

The output will be

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```